# LINQ query select entity and its collection query

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6.1

I have an entity called Parent which has List of Children in it.
now i want to select a parent and all its children order by display order.

```
    entities:- class parent{
                          Int id;
                          List<Child> children;
                           }

                class Child{ 
                            String name;
                            DateTime DOB;
                            Int DisplayOrder;
                           }
```

earlier i was getting a parent from Database using Linq to Entity as

```
                context.Parents.Find(id);
```

This was doing everything fine. but now my requirement has changed now i need to select its children order by their display order. how can i do that. Any help is appreciated.

update parent class:-

```
              class parent{
                        public  Int id;
                        public virtual List<Child> children;
                           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From info you provided I guess that you using your `children` somewhere to display them so you can use just `parent.children.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList()` instead of simply `parent.children` that I suppose you had before.

**Update 1.**

Also I as far as I remember `Find` won't include your children. So worth to try something like:

```
var parent = context.Parents.Include(x => x.children).FirstOrDefault(x => x.id = id);
parent.children = parent.children.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList();
```

Comment: no i accessed model.children in my .cshtml file there i used for loop instead of foreach. i cant change that that is why i was asking if i can get parent with children in sorted order from db itself

Comment: @iGod I am pretty sure that you will be able to change that, just show you usage? You will be able to create another local variable where you will store reordered **children** and you will be able to make your loop against that.

Comment: Hi Vlad, against your updated comment(sorry i was using that). find was including children also and just now i came up with this solution "parent.children = parent.children.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList()". but is it fine?

Comment: @iGod that depends on you application design and avg amount of child records, but there is no way to select parent with ordered children records. Only thing you can do there - perform that ordering on SQL server side: from p in context.Parents.Find(id) select new {id = p.id, children = p.children.OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder) }

Answer (score 0):

You have the Order By command on list, you can send to controller the "column" and order by this column

Comment: I didn`t get your point. i need to fetch a parent based on id passed and all it`s children also order by display order

Comment: but you can use context.Parents.Find(id).OrderBy(order => order.DisplayOrder);

Comment: it will not work as you cant use orderby extension after Find(). and moreover display order property is for children not parent

Answer (score 0):

That's in case you are sure that there can be only one parent with given ID.

```
var parent = context.Parents.Find(id);
parent.children = parent.children.OrderBy(cl => cl.DisplayOrder).ToList();
```

Comment: i was thinking of the same. but i doubt is it the right approach

Comment: @iGod For sure it's working. But maybe it's not the best solution. Ordering parent.children itself will not work though.